# Hint about proving $\lim_{n \to \infty}( \sqrt{\log{(x_n + a)}} - \sqrt{\log{x_n}} ) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to prove that for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and while $\lim x_n = \infty$, $\lim_{n \to \infty}( \sqrt{\log{(x_n + a)}} - \log{\sqrt{x_n}} ) = 0$. While a full proof would be nice (it may avoid future questions), I am only requesting a simple hint about how to simplify $\sqrt{\log{(x_n + a)}} - \log{\sqrt{x_n}}$. This is an exercise from "Analise Real. Funções de Uma Variável - Volume 1" by Elon Lima. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Yes, this is typo in the translation I was reading. My apologies to everyone. $\sqrt{\log{(x_n + a)}} - \sqrt{\log{x_n}}$ is the correct expression. I modified the title accordingly.

Comment: That looks wrong, pick $a=0$ and $x_n=n^2$. Then we have $$ \sqrt{\log(n^2)} - \log(n)= \log(n)\left( \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\log(n)}} -1\right).$$ This goes to $-\infty$.

Comment: Do you mean $\sqrt{\log(x_n+a)}-\sqrt{\log(x_n)}?$

Comment: $\sqrt{\log x}$ and $\frac12\log x$ have different asymptotics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a typo in the question,

$$\sqrt{\log{(x_n + a)}} -\sqrt{\log{{x_n}}}=\frac{\log{(x_n + a)} -\log{{x_n}}}{\sqrt{\log{(x_n + a)}}+\sqrt{\log{{x_n}}}}.$$

The numerator tends to $0$ and the denominator to $\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Composing Taylor series gives the result
$$\log(x+a)=\log (x)+\frac{a}{x}-\frac{a^2}{2 x^2}+\frac{a^3}{3
   x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)$$
$$\sqrt{\log(x+a)}=\sqrt{\log (x)}+\frac{a}{2 x \sqrt{\log (x)}}-\frac{a^2 (2 \log (x)+1)}{8 x^2
   \log (x)\sqrt{\log (x)}}+\cdots$$
$$\sqrt{\log(x+a)}-\sqrt{\log(x)}\sim \frac{a}{2 x \sqrt{\log (x)}}$$

Try for $x=10^6$ and $a=12345$. The "exact" value is $0.001650$ and the approximation gives $0.001661$.